# Javascript Count Up Timer - How can I keep it from starting over on refresh?

Tags: javascript, cookies, counter

I built a count up timer with JS to gradually count up to a number, but every time I refresh it resets. How can I make it so it doesn't reset every time?

```
    const speed = 200; // The lower the slower

    counters.forEach(counter => {
    const updateCount = () => {
        const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
        const count = +counter.innerText;

        // Lower inc to slow and higher to slow
        const inc = 1;
    

        // console.log(inc);
        // console.log(count);

        // Check if target is reached
        if (count < target) {
            // Add inc to count and output in counter
            counter.innerText = count + inc;
            // Call function every ms
            setTimeout(updateCount, 10000);
            
        } else {
            counter.innerText = target;
        }
    };

    updateCount();
});
```

Comment: everytime you refresh the page the code is being run from the beginning again, you would need to either cache the time, so when they reload the page the variable is loaded from that (however if they clear cache they can restart the timer) or get the time from an external website/api

Comment: Look into the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).